# How to handle building files outside of directory

Tags: scons

I have a build set up and I'm struggling on how to handle one aspect.
I have successfully setup a variantdir for my project folder src build output, however I have
source that resides outside the project folder that needs to be build and included.

I am able to add the files I need into the build, however the object files are put into the external directory where the library souce files are.

Is there a standard way to solve this. I would like to avoid adding any scons files to the external directory as it is a standard intall of a tool.

What I attempted was to Mkdir() a temporary folder, Copy() the files, and build the files. This seems to work, but only the first time as the file permissions are set to readonly. Also, the only way to get it to work seemed to be to use the Execute() command which caused the action to happen at every build.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Repository() method (see http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-repositories in the [SCons UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html)). It lets you sort of "mount" a folder to the top-level of your source tree. Then you can refer to them locally, and specifying "duplicate=1" for your variant dir should keep your remote folder clean from built files.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the functionality I was looking for by building the objects in the external directory and then using the Move() Factory to move the object files.

If Anyone can point out a more 'scons'sy way of doing it please let me know.