# Scons and external directories

Tags: python, scons

I am working with a scons build system for building shared libraries. Everything builds fine up to this part but now I am having some difficulties.

I cannot get scons to move the output file to a directory outside of the scons folder structure.

The only thing that I've sen on SO about it is this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747512/how-to-handle-building-files-outside-of-directory)

If I try to write a python function to do it, the function runs first before the build finishes so I get some file not found errors.

How can I get scons to move a file to a directory outside of the directory where SConstruct file is defined?

```
import os
import shutil

Import('env')

android_files = [

    'os_android.cpp',
    'pic_android.cpp',
    'file_access_android.cpp',
    'dir_access_android.cpp',
    'audio_driver_opensl.cpp',
    'file_access_jandroid.cpp',
    'dir_access_jandroid.cpp',
    'thread_jandroid.cpp',
    'audio_driver_jandroid.cpp',
    'ifaddrs_android.cpp',
    'android_native_app_glue.c',
    'java_glue.cpp',
    'cpu-features.c',
    'java_class_wrapper.cpp'
]

env = env.Clone()

if env['target'] == "profile":
    env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DPROFILER_ENABLED'])

android_objects=[]
for x in android_files:
    android_objects.append( env.SharedObject( x ) )

prog = None

abspath=env.Dir(".").abspath


pp_basein = open(abspath+"/project.properties.template","rb")
pp_baseout = open(abspath+"/java/project.properties","wb")
pp_baseout.write( pp_basein.read() )

refcount=1

name="libpic"+env["SHLIBSUFFIX"]
dir="#bin/"+name
output=dir[1:]
ANDROID_HOME=os.environ.get('ANDROID_HOME')
ant_build=Dir('.').abspath+"/java/"
ANT_TARGET=ant_build+'local.properties'
ANT_SOURCES=ant_build+'build.xml'
ANDROID_HOME=os.environ.get('ANDROID_HOME')
ANT_COMMAND='ant release -Dsdk.dir='+ANDROID_HOME+' -f $SOURCE'

for x in env.android_source_modules:
    pp_baseout.write("android.library.reference."+str(refcount)+"="+x+"\n")
    refcount+=1

pp_baseout.close()


pp_basein = open(abspath+"/AndroidManifest.xml.template","rb")
pp_baseout = open(abspath+"/java/AndroidManifest.xml","wb")
manifest = pp_basein.read()
manifest = manifest.replace("$$ADD_APPLICATION_CHUNKS$$",env.android_manifest_chunk)
pp_baseout.write( manifest )


for x in env.android_source_files:
    shutil.copy(x,abspath+"/java/src/com/android/pic")  

for x in env.android_module_libraries:
    shutil.copy(x,abspath+"/java/libs") 


env.SharedLibrary("#bin/libpic",[android_objects],SHLIBSUFFIX=env["SHLIBSUFFIX"])

env.Command('#platform/android/java/libs/armeabi/libpic_android.so', dir, Copy('platform/android/java/libs/armeabi/libpic_android.so', output))

apk = env.Command(ANT_TARGET, source=ANT_SOURCES, action=ANT_COMMAND)

#env.Install('[install_dir]', apk)
#Cannot get this part to work, tried env.Install() but donno
#if env['target'] == 'release_debug'
    #copy 'platform/android/java/bin/Pic-release-unsigned.apk' to templates as 'android_debug.apk'
#else:
    #copy 'platform/android/java/bin/Pic-release-unsigned.apk' to templates as 'android_release.apk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the [SCons Install Builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-install). This is the only way to install targets outside of the SCons project hierarchy.

Comment: When I used the install builder it tacks on the location right at the end of my current working directory. so I'll put install in "/Users/dev/install/" but I'll get /Users/dev/pic/src/platform/Users/dev/install which seems really odd.

Comment: @steffan that does seem odd. Can you show your code?

Comment: I'll update the original post with the code. A few comments towards the end.